# XSD validation: N children with additional, different constraints

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have XML that I want to validate using an XSD. It's actually a simple scenario but I could not find the right answer. This is the XML:

```
<data>
  <point>
    <x>count</x>
    <y>218</y>
  </point>
  <point>
    <x>maxtime</x>
    <y>1</y>
  </point>
  <point>
    <x>mintime</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </point>
  <point>
    <x>mean</x>
    <y>0.11</y>
  </point>
</data>
```

I want to make sure that the *data* element contains 4 *point* elements and that there is only one with *x* element = *count*, only one with  *x* = *maxtime*...

What I have now is the following:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="point" type="ctPoint" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="ctPoint">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4">
        <xs:element name="x" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="count" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="maxtime" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="mintime" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="mean" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="y" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This validates correctly but it does not guarantee that there is only 1 count, only 1 maxtime,…

Comment: You most probably can't with XSD 1.0. Can you use XSD 1.1?

Comment: I can also use XSD 1.1 but how do I do it there?

Comment: If I have understand your problem right, its also possible in XSD 1.0 using xs:unique (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I want to make sure that the data element contains 4 point elements
```

**This constraint you can do simply with XSD 1.0's `minOccurs="4"` and `maxOccurs="4"`.**

> and that there is only one with x element = count, only one with x =
>   maxtime...

**This constraint would have to be done out-of-band (in code) if you're stuck with XSD 1.0.**

[**Update**: However, see @sergioFC's [good XSD 1.0 idea about `xs:unique`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27317740/290085) if the intent is simply to have *all* `x` values be unique within `data`.]

If you can use **XSD 1.1**, as @lexicore suggested, it would work.  Use `xs:assert`:

```
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="point" type="ctPoint" minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="4" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count(point[x = 'count']) = 1 and
                       count(point[x = 'maxtime']) = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **xs:uniqe** which **is also valid in XSD 1.0**.

```
<xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="point" type="ctPoint" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="myUnique">
        <!-- Select all points in data -->
        <xs:selector xpath="point" />
        <!-- The value of x of every selected point should be unique -->
        <xs:field xpath="x" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

In addition, in order to do that, I think you should change *minOccurs* as user kjhughes has said in his answer.

Comment: This is a good idea and may help OP, however, note that ensuring that all `x` elements are unique is not the same as requiring there  be only one of `x` elements with certain string values.  For example, your XSD would allow x=1, x=2, x=3, x=4.  It would also disallow x=count, x=maxtime, x=1, x=1.

Comment: @kjhughes I think that this is correct because the values of x are restricted in the OP enumeration.

Comment: Ok, you're right about x=1, x=2, x=3, x=4 because of the enumeration restriction, which I forgot was there.  However, your XSD would still disallow x=count, x=maxtime, x=mean, x=mean, for example.   ...But now that I re-read OP's requirement, there is a '...' after his "only one with" constraint so there's a good chance you're right that all are supposed to be unique.  Ok, you've got my +1.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you :) I had also given you +1 because of the correct assertions approach and the *occurs* info.